# How to correctly write a condition in switch?

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon!
Why does the first option work - switch (true), and the second option does not work - switch (a)?

First:

```
var a= prompt('Enter value', '');
switch(true)
{
    case a>10:
        alert('a>10');
    break;

    case a<10:
        alert('a<10');
    break;

    default:
        alert('a===10');
```

Second:

```
var a= prompt('Enter value', '');
switch(a)
{
    case a>10:
        alert('a>10');
    break;

    case a<10:
        alert('a<10');
    break;

    default:
        alert('a===10');
```

Comment: That's an interesting use of `switch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the first option work - switch (true), and the second option
>   does not work - switch (a)?

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the
>   expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements
>   associated with that case.

So, in your **first option** `true` will match to either `a < 10` or `a > 10`, however in **second option**, *`a` being a string* may not match to either of them.

Comment: at last proper answer for question.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас it's нормально

Comment: maybe worth to mention the strict comparison.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit:*** I just realize OP ask for the difference instead of why it won't work, sorry for misunderstanding the question

---

It should work nicely

```js
var a = prompt('Enter value', '');

switch (true) {
    case (a > 10):
        alert("a > 10");
        break;

    case (a < 10):
        alert("a < 10");
        break;

    default:
        alert('a == 10');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a > 10` is `true`, like the `switch(true)`, while `switch(a)` was passed `a`, which is not `true`. Of course, you should cast `a`. `a = +a` or use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Here's what you probably meant to do:

```js
var a = prompt('Enter value');
if(+a > 10){
  alert('a > 10');
}
else if(a !== '' && +a < 10){
  alert('a < 10');
}
else if(+a === 10){
  alert('a === 10'); 
}
else{
  alert('Really, you should avoid using prompt and alert!');
}
// notice this is less code than that pointless switch
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert the user input from a string to an integer, like so

```
a = parseInt(a)
```

Comment: JS already does it for you. It's because of the `switch(a)` part.